# Iterate string array error, runs for first item's letters

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a simple array loop, runs perfect in jsFiddle showing all items, see https://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/b27ocs4d/1/

What's strange is that putting the same script here as a snippet runs by letter, showing the first string letter by letter. I feel stupid, am I missing something? Check it out:

```js
var name = ['Helen','Jim','Thomas','Luke','Theodore'];
var div = document.getElementById('cards');
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
 var newHtml = name[i]+'&emsp;'+i+'</br>';
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + newHtml;   
}
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

Comment: looks like name is treated as a string here and not array

Comment: here is an overwiev of js's reserved words: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `name` is a property of `window` and it has a setter which converts the input value to a string. Your code is trying to assign an array to that property which is magically converted to a string:

```js
var name = ["foo", "bar"];
console.log(name); // array converted to "foo,bar"
```

So why does it work on jsFiddle? The answer is that, by default, jsFiddle wraps your code inside a function, something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/99mm894v/1/):

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var name = ["foo", "bar"];
    console.log(name); // ["foo", "bar"]
  }
</script>
```

This creates a closure where `var name` creates a new variable instead of referring to `window.name`. If you change your jsFiddle settings (JavaScript tab > Load type > No wrap - in body) then you get the same result as the StackSnippet [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/99mm894v/3/):

```
<script>
  var name = ["foo", "bar"];
  console.log(name); // "foo,bar"
</script>
```

The solution is not to pollute the global namespace in the first place. That way you do not have to lookup the list of "words not to use as JavaScript variables".

Answer (score 3):

Word `name` is a [reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) (as @prasad answered) in javascript that why your code was not working as expected.

See below code, after changing `name` with `names`. Its seems working as was working in jsfiddle.

```js
var names = ['Helen','Jim','Thomas','Luke','Theodore'];
var div = document.getElementById('cards');
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
 var newHtml = names[i]+'&emsp;'+i+'</br>';
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + newHtml;   
}
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

Note: `name` can only be used as local variable inside a function or iife and can not used as global varibale.

Comment: Name is not a reserved word in Javascript!!! It is a variable in the global scope used by the browser to define the window name.

Comment: To be clear, as the above link states *"These are predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties (and, arguably, some should have been reserved words)"*

Answer (score 2):

Try any one of the function its working.  `name` is **[reserved](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)** word of javascript.But applied with in function .Its not act as a reserved word.This is one of the way preventing the action.

```js
(function () {
var name = ["Helen","Jim","Thomas","Luke","Theodore"];
var div = document.getElementById('cards');
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  var newHtml = name[i]+'&emsp;'+i+'</br>';
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + newHtml;   
}
  })()
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

Comment: this works because the name attribut has no global scope anymore.

Comment: Name is not a reserved word in Javascript. It is the name of the window and is thus a variable. You simply can not assign a value to any reserved words or use a reserved word as a variable anywhere within any javascript context, or scope. -1

Answer (score 1):

### `name` AKA `window.name`

Well `name` is most definitely not a reserved word in javascript.

`name` AKA `window.name` is the name of the window. Its value is set by a setter function and as the window name should be a string. So when you set it with `name=["foo","bar"]` it is converted to a string.

It is unfortunate that Javascript must share the global name space with every man and his dog and this illustrates another reason to avoid the global scope whenever possible.